# How to start a program using a hotkey in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, hotkeys, root

I'm making a program using C#, the user should be blind person. I've done everything but I remembered that the blind user can't start the application like any person.

So is it possible in C# to add the program to the startup programs list and send it to the tray, and when the user presses Esc key for example, the program starts.

Thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's can be done without any connection to c#, follow this instructions:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Create-keyboard-shortcuts-to-open-programs?SignedIn=1

or tutorial:

http://www.butterscotch.com/tutorial/Launch-A-Program-With-Windows-Hotkeys